# Center footer wrt paper, not margins

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Im writing a thesis. The requirements are 1.5in left margin and 1 in right. In addition, the page number must be in the right hand corner except on the first page of every chapter where it must be centered in the footer. Im using the fancyhdr package which centers the footer with respect to the text and not the page. Id like to center the footer so the page number is centered on the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=1.5in, right=1in,top=1in, bottom=1in}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
 \fancyhead{}
 \fancyhead[RE, RO]{\thepage}
 \fancyfoot{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}

first page

\pagebreak

second page

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This would look weird, in my point of view

Comment: Thank you. That may be so but those are the requirements.

Comment: if i understand the requirements page number go to text center not page center

Comment: `In addition, the first page must be in the right hand corner except on the first page of every chapter`: what does this mean? The first page goes to the right-hand corner of what? Itself?

Comment: Edited that typo. Also, I submitted it today and was told it must be page center(Which seems to defeat the purpose of the unequal margins).

Comment: @touhami Remember: these are thesis requirements. They are being interpreted by the bureaucrats who typically administer these things. You are making the mistake of assuming they will interpret them as any sane, sensible, reasonable person would do.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Of course it will look weird. It is a thesis. The requirements always require them to look weird. I think that must be part of the design specification.

Comment: @cfr: I am still quite clad that there were no design restrictions when I wrote my thesis about 10 years ago ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I went through this twice. When they get out a ruler and tell you that your title or heading is 2mm too high, you know that you are dealing with Insanity. After that, all you care about is that they accept the damn thing - what it looks like becomes immaterial.

Answer (score 4):

That a-way? I replaced `fancyhdr` with `titleps` from the `titlesec` bundle, defined a `weird` page style, and redefined the plain style.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=1.5in, right=1in,top=1in, bottom=1in, showframe, nomarginpar}
\setcounter{page}{900}

\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{weird}{%
\sethead{}{}{\thepage}
}%
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\setfoot{}{\makebox[0pt]{\thepage}\hskip0.5in}{}
}%
 \pagestyle{weird}

\setcounter{page}{900}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}
% 
first page

\pagebreak %

second page

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cfr: Not any more. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Werner: It doesn't affect any more (I think): I (re)defined page styles with `titleps`.

Comment: (+1) This seems saner to me. No need to make more trouble for the OP than the thesis office already intend to! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another suggestion using `scrlayer`. Then you can redeclare `plain` as a layer pagestyle with only one layer containing the centred page number.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1in,
  left=2.5in,% enlarged in this example
  showframe}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    foreground,
    foot,
    hoffset=0pt,
    width=\paperwidth,
    contents={\parbox{\layerwidth}{\centering\thepage}}
]{PageMarkCentredToPage}
\RedeclarePageStyleByLayers{plain}{PageMarkCentredToPage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
first page
\clearpage
second page
\end{document}
```

Note that I have also enlarged the left margin to show the effect.
[image]

---

Of course you can also replace `fancyhdr` by `scrlayer-scrpage` that is based on `scrlayer`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1in,
  left=3.5in,% enlarged in this example
  showframe}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\rohead{\pagemark}
\rehead{\pagemark}

\DeclareNewLayer[
    foreground,
    foot,
    hoffset=0pt,
    width=\paperwidth,
    contents={\parbox{\layerwidth}{\centering\thepage}}
]{PageMarkCentredToPage}
\RedeclarePageStyleByLayers{plain}{PageMarkCentredToPage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
first page
\clearpage
second page
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this work?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=1.5in, right=1in,top=1in, bottom=1in, showframe}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
 \fancyhead{}
 \fancyhead[RE, RO]{\thepage}
 \fancyfoot{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
 \fancyhf[cf]{\thepage\makebox[.25in]{ }}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}

first page

\pagebreak

second page

\end{document}
```

[image: weird page numbering requirement]

Comment: Its fixed the centering issue, but the page number for every page is now in the footer

Comment: @Mary Well, that's what you said you wanted: `... except on the first page of every chapter where it must be centered in the footer`. What did I miss?

Comment: @Mary Wait. *For every page*? That is not true in the MWE I posted so it is hard to know what would cause that.

Comment: Sorry for the typos...Not enough sleep.  Anyways, my table of contents section must be number with roman numerals. So I added the following before that section : \pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{2}
\pagestyle{plain}     After i removed that it worked.

Comment: @Mary OK. Good - mystery solved. `plain` will be used automatically for the first pages of chapters (including the ToC) and `fancy` for the others. Whether the numbers are Arabic or Roman is independent of that, so just switching the numbering as you've now done should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work after the second compilation (first time around), regardless of the margin dimensions. The principle is to set two markers (using [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)) on the first page to capture the x and y coordinates needed on the page (stored using [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module. Subsequently, the page number for "special pages" (in this case, the `plain` page style pages, associated with the first page of every `\chapter`) will be moved into position.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{geometry,eso-pic,zref-savepos}
\geometry{
  margin=1in,
  left=1.5in,
  right=3in,% Just for this example
  showframe}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[RE, RO]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\specialthepage}}

% Place reference markers on first page
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{% Just in the background of first page only
    \AtPageCenter{\zsaveposx{page-center}}% At page centre, capture x-pos
    \AtTextLowerLeft{\zsaveposy{page-footer}}% At text lower left, capture y-pos
  }%
}%

% \specialthepage is issued only on \pagestyle{plain}, which is first page of \chapter
\newcommand{\specialthepage}{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{% Just in foreground of current page only
    \hspace*{\zposx{page-center}sp}% Move to horizontal center
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\zposy{page-footer}sp-\footskip}{\makebox[0pt]{\thepage}}% Raise to text block lower-left level - footer skip
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}

first page

\clearpage

second page
```

In the above example, I've used `twoside` mode and a bizarre `right` margin just for show.

Comment: My solution requires only one compilation ;o)

Comment: @Bernard: Mine requires two, and thereafter only one. So 1 more in total. I know, it's a mess to require that from users.

Comment: My  solution seems so simple that I have doubts concerning its general validity…